# How can i get all the objects from a XML serialized file using XMLdecoder?

Tags: java, serialization

I have a custom Stack which uses a custom SinglyLinkedList.
I want to serialize the objects from the Stack and deserialize them also.

For serialization part i used this method:

```
public void serializeToFile(Stack oStack, String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException{

    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder(os);

    while(!oStack.isEmpty()){
        encoder.writeObject(oStack.pop());           
    }
    encoder.close();
}
```

it seems to work fine, generating the file with one object after another.
The question is how can i get back all these objects(deserialised) to a stack(my own self defined stack)?

I thought like this:

```
public Stack deserializeFromFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{

    Stack oStack = new Stack();

    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder(is);

    oStack.push(decoder.readObject());

    return oStack;
}
```

but this takes only the first object. Is there a way to deserialise object by object until eof? What other options do i have?
Thanks!

Comment: Before writing any of your stack elements, write an int which is the total number of elements in the stack.  Then, when reading, you can read the count first, and you'll know how many times to subsequently call readObject in a loop.

Comment: Genius! It works. Thank you! Related to this solution are there any portability problems (that int that is not of same type as the rest of the objects)?

Comment: I don't believe so.  XMLEncoder and XMLDecoder are able to handle primitive types.  Have a look at your XML file to see how they do it.